# Derivatives of multivariate normal CDF in terms of lower-dimension PDFs and CDFs

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a standardized multivariate normal distribution of dimensionality $m$, parameterized either by the correlation matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$:

$$
X_m \sim N_c(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\mathbf{\Sigma}})
$$

or by the precision matrix (inverse of the correlation matrix) $\Lambda = \mathbf{\mathbf{\Sigma}}^{-1}$:
$$
X_m \sim N_p(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\mathbf{\Lambda}})
$$

(whichever is most convenient for the solution)

I am interested in the derivative of the CDF (cumulative distribution function)
$$
\mathbf{\Phi}_m(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\Sigma}) = P(\mathbf{y}_m \sim N(\mathbf{0}_m, \mathbf{\Sigma}_{m \times m}) \geq \mathbf{x}_m)
$$

with respect to each entry in $\mathbf{x}$ - that is:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \mathbf{\Phi}_m(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\Sigma}), \:\:
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \mathbf{\Phi}_m(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\Sigma}), \:\:
... \:\:, \:\:
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_m} \mathbf{\Phi}_m(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\Sigma})
$$

From this other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71976/partial-derivative-of-bivariate-normal-cdf-and-pdf

When $m=2$, if the upper triangular part of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is expressed as a vector $(\rho_{12} \:\: \rho_{13} \:\: ... \:\: \rho_{23} \:\: \rho_{24} \:\: ...  \:\:\rho_{mm})$ and we denote as $\phi_m(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ the PDF of an $m$-dimensional MVN distribution, we have:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \mathbf{\Phi}_2(x_1, x_2, \rho_{12}) =
\phi_1(x_1)
\mathbf{\Phi}_1(\frac{x_2 - \rho_{12} x_1}{\sqrt{1 - \rho_{12}^2}})
$$

And:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \mathbf{\Phi}_2(x_1, x_2, \rho_{12}) =
\phi_1(x_2)
\mathbf{\Phi}_1(\frac{x_1 - \rho_{12} x_2}{\sqrt{1 - \rho_{12}^2}})
$$

---

Can an arbitrary-dimension multivariate normal CDF be expressed in terms of the PDFs and CDFs of lower-dimensional multivariate normal distributions?

I suspect the formula might be something like this:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_p} \mathbf{\Phi}_m(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\Sigma}) =
\phi_{1}(x_p)
\mathbf{\Phi}_{m-1}(
    \frac{x_1 - \rho_{1p} x_p}{\sqrt{1 - \rho_{1p}^2}},
    \frac{x_2 - \rho_{2p} x_p}{\sqrt{1 - \rho_{2p}^2}},
    \:\: ... \:\:;
    \Lambda_{1p},
    \Lambda_{2p},
    ...
)
$$

But I am very unsure about it.

What would be the correct formula?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer myself after finding a book called "Stochastic Programming" by András Prékopa (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-3087-7) plus this other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330966/derivative-of-the-joint-distribution-interpretation

Given a multivariate CDF $\text{CDF}_m(x_1, x_2, \: ... \:, x_m)$, we have:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \text{CDF}_m(x_1, x_2, \: ... \:, x_m) =
    \text{PDF}_1(x1) \:\:
    \text{CDF}_{m-1}(x_2, \: ... \: , x_m \:|\: x_1)
$$

For MVN, denoting $\mathbf{x}_{-1} = (x_2 \:,\: ... \:,\: x_m)$ and
$$
\mathbf{S} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{S}_{11} & \mathbf{S}_{12} \\
    \mathbf{S}_{21} & \mathbf{S}_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}
    =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{1, 2..m} \\
    \mathbf{\Sigma}_{1, 2..m} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{2..m, 2..m} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We have:
$$
\phi_{m-1}(x_2, \: ... \: , x_m \:|\: x_1 = c) =
\phi_{m-1}(
    x_1 + \mathbf{S}_{12} \mathbf{S}_{22}^{-1} (c - \mathbf{x}_{-1}), \:\:
    1 - \mathbf{S}_{12} \mathbf{S}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{S}_{21}
)
$$

Then, as defined by Henrion's "GRADIENT ESTIMATES FOR GAUSSIAN DISTRIBUTION FUNCTIONS: APPLICATION TO PROBABILISTICALLY CONSTRAINED OPTIMIZATION PROBLEMS" paper:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \mathbf{\Phi}_{m}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\Sigma}) =
    \phi_{1}(x_1, 1) \:
    \mathbf{\Phi}_{m-1}(
        \mathbf{\widetilde{x}}, \:
        \mathbf{\widetilde{\Sigma}}
    )
$$

With:
$$
\mathbf{\widetilde{x}} = \left(
    \frac{x_2 - \Sigma_{2,1} x_1}{\sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{2,1}^2}} \:,\:
    ... \:,\:
    \frac{x_m - \Sigma_{m,1} x_1}{\sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{m,1}^2}}
\right)
$$

and
$$
\mathbf{\widetilde{\Sigma}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \frac{\Sigma_{2,3} - \Sigma_{2,1} \Sigma_{3,1}}{\sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{2,1}^2} \sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{3,1}^2}}
    & \: ... & \: &
    \frac{ \Sigma_{2,m} - \Sigma_{2,1} \Sigma_{m,1}  }{ \sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{2,1}^2}  \sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{m,1}^2}}   \\
    & 1 & 
    \frac{ \Sigma_{3,4} - \Sigma_{3,1} \Sigma_{4,1} }{ \sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{3,1}^2}   \sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{4,1}^2} } &
    \: ... \: &
    \frac{ \Sigma_{3,m} - \Sigma_{3,1} \Sigma_{m,1} }{ \sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{3,1}^2}   \sqrt{1 - \Sigma_{m,1}^2} } \\
    & & \: ... \: & &
\end{bmatrix}
$$